# Getting repeated timeout when calling stream-based web service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, webservice-client

[Calling a stream-based web service](http://pastebin.com/8cagdfhz) but keep getting a timeout exception (`System.Web.Net.Exception`).

All the advice I've been able to find on the net asks me to set the timeouts.  Here is my configuration:

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEntity"  maxBufferSize="65536"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" >
      <readerQuotas  maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
```

I am still getting timeouts and it is getting frustrating.  Another web service (for logins) on the same server at a similar URL works fine. This second web service is not stream-based.

Is there something wrong with the way I am submitting to the web service? I've verified that the parameters I am submitting are correct.

Comment: Could you add the linked snippet to the question? I think it may be helpful to others in the future when they come to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `BasicHttpBinding` is for communicating with SOAP web services (SOAP 1.1 to be precise). The client code you linked to is consuming the web service as if it were a RESTful service.

It is *possible* to use the `WebClient` class to consume a WCF SOAP web service, but I wouldn't recommend it. If this service is a SOAP web service, then I advise  generating a proxy via the WSDL and using that to communicate with the service. If the service is actually a WCF RESTful service, then you must you the `WebHttpBinding` and add the `WebHttpBehavior` to the service endpoint.